# How to fix wall with internal water damage

Tags: drywall, water-damage, condensation

We had some work done in our home and we had the attic exposed, with a window open, and the AC running all day long. This caused one of the ducts, which lacked insulation, to sweat and drop all the sweat into the ceiling, which ran down the wall.

I am having the attic insulated more to cover the duct. Do I need to remove this sheetrock and replace it? Sand, mud, and paint it? What's the best way to make this wall look normal again?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: A dehumidifier and a fan are your go to tools with damp Sheetrock. A dehumidifier will pull the moisture from the air a fan pushes air over the Sheetrock and assists with drying. It is very easy to damage wet Sheetrock, give it a chance to dry.

Comment: And how long ago was the leak?

Comment: Leak was a week ago @JACK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd insulate that duct. If this was just a one time leak, I don't think replacing the sheetrock is necessary. Examine the damage from the attic and check the area for dampness. If you see any mold spray some vinegar over the area to kill it.

Sand the wall with a block sander or an orbital one and remove all the imperfections. You will probably have to re tape the section going toward the vent. Wait a few days just to make sure the area is completely dry. Then you can prime and paint.

Comment: I would not do anything until the wall dries out or the op would be replacing the section.

Comment: @EdBeal  Definitely... I was thinking the wall had already pretty much dried out.

Comment: There's hopefully no rush here, so it's important the drywall is indeed "dry wall" (pun intended!)  And not trying to be a "Karen" here, but I will state my usual advice on dust control:  Cover much of the work area with painters plastic tarp, wear a true respirator (not just a fabric mask), wear a hat.  When done sanding, change your clothes and toss them in the wash, maybe take a shower.  No need to go full hazmat, just sensible precautions. Many DIYers don't take dust control seriously enough.

Comment: "Sand the wall with a block sander or an orbital one" If this is drywall, an orbital sander is likely to _rapidly_ chew through the paint then the outer paper layer leaving the gypsum core exposed. I'd hand sand just to prevent further damage.